# The same display name for several versions of one iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, bundle, product

Can I assign the same display name for several versions of one iPhone App.
The game, I’m finishing now, has 4 versions:

- iPhone only - Paid
- iPhone only - Free
- iPad only - Paid
- iPad only - Free

The name displayed on the springboard is pretty long, and it barely fits the space under the icon. One more char and it would be truncated. So if I add any suffix (i.e. “HD”, “free” or “HD free”) it would be unreadable.

My question is: Will Apple reject my apps if I assign the same Product Name (which would change Bundle Name and Bundle Display Name) and make different icons indicating the version?

I guess somebody have tried to do this before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use same display name for several versions - tested.

I had several sister-apps in App Store and they all shared same display name
(and different icons). They were merged into one app later but answer to your
question is: it shouldn't be a problem.

Just make sure this will not confuse your customers.

Comment: Can I just set the same Product Name in build settings won't it cause any conflicts? Or is it better to set just the bundle name in info.plist file and keep Product Names different?

Comment: Don't change the product name - they should be uniquer. Only bundle display names can be the same - you should modify those directly, not trough modifying product name.